# How do I make MvcBuildViews continue to other views on error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I've got a handy visual studio external tool shortcut to build the current project with MvcBuildViews enabled.

Arguments: `/m:2 $(ProjectFileName) /p:MvcBuildViews=true`
Command Line: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /m:2 "ProviderPortal.csproj" /p:MvcBuildViews=true`

Anytime there is an error on a view, it stops at that one and reports it.
I want to know all the views that have errors not just stop at the first one.

How would I tell the Aspnet-Compiler to continue on errors? Or is there a way to get msbuild to instead invoke the aspnet-compiler per view rather than a one-shot call?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting ContinueOnError to ErrorAndContinue:

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" ContinueOnError="ErrorAndContinue" />
</Target>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171484.aspx

Comment: Doesn't work for me - I still have to fix the errors in one view before it will show the next. Anyone have further suggestions?

Comment: ContinueOnError controls how MSBuild behaves to the task. So if the task fails it continues with next one. But it does not configure how the task behaves internally :-( - which is I guess what author is asking for.